# Find me in the pictures

Tags: visual

You **can't** find me here:

[image: You can't find me here]

But **here** is **part** of me:

[image]

And here is another:

[image]

What am I?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Possibly:

> X-Ray

Because:

> The X comes from the map in the third picture.
>  The ray comes from the stingray in the second picture.
>  X (which is 10 in roman numeral) is not found in a sudoku (credits to @A J).

Comment: Try figuring out the But in your answer. :)

Comment: This is what I was going to answer! The sudoku might be that there is no x in sudoku?

Comment: @naffarn The above comment might be a spoiler (it gives part of the answer) :)

Answer (score 8):

Are you

> The sea / C. There is no C in sudoku, neither the word nor the picture.
>  The next picture shows a stingray or some sort of ray in the sea.
>  The third picture shows a treasure map surrounded by sea.
>  The sea is big, so each picture only depicts part of it.

Comment: This is not the answer. Good try!

Answer (score 7):

The answer is

> X-Ray

How

Second image

> of a bat- ray.

Third image

> X

First Image

> X (Roman numeral for 10) is not found in Sudoku, because there are only 0-9 numbers filled in it.

Comment: Could be a comment on @Klokje88's answer...

Comment: This is what I meant. I am accepting the answer of Klokje88 only because he explained better the other two images and was the first to guess it, but I have upvoted yours as well.

Comment: @IAmInPLS Actually I didn't see Klokje88's answer while posting mine.

Answer (score 3):

Is it:

> 'Crocodile Hunter' Steve Irwin?

Because:

> The map image is 'X marks the spot' which is an expression used by the British Army, who performed executions by marking a piece of paper with a black x and positioning it on the heart of someone sentenced to death. And the stingray on the other image killed Irwin by piercing him in the heart. And the Sudoku puzzle states that the answer is not there.

Comment: No, it is not. :)